# Error adding event listener, says element is null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm removing inline event handlers and replacing them with event listeners. When the page loads there is the error message `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`. What am I doing wrong?

```
//adding function listeners
var inputEl = document.getElementById('us');
inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', availability, false); // error here

function availability(name, availabilityDiv)
{
    var name = document.getElementById('us').value;
        //code sniped
}
```

`<input type="text" name="us" id="us" />`

I know my code is rather strange so let me explain. I want to call a function each time a character is entered into an input field and I want the characters entered to be passed to the function as an argument. If there's a better way of doing this do tell.

Comment: If the script comes before the element then the element won't exist when the script runs and it is therefore `null` and the code fails. Make sense?

Comment: availability is spelled wrong.

Comment: Very much. So how do I go from inline event handling to using an action listener?

Comment: make the script come after the element, just before `</body>` is fine. If you get it right, you will probably discover the ReferenceError caused by the typo next :)

Comment: I was unclear about where to place JS and learned from [this source](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptheadnbody.php) where it says "If you want to have a script run on some event, such as when a user clicks somewhere, then you will place that script in the head." Is this information out dated?

Comment: @Celeritas, if you are placing the script in the head it has to be run after the `onload` event. ex `window.onload = function(){....}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: You can just move your script to the bottom of the page rather than in the head. Also, *addEventListener* is not supported in IE 8, which is more than half of all IE users. Look for an *addEvent* function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are placing your script in the header, then it has to be run on the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/window.onload) event

ex

```
window.onload = function(){

    //adding function listeners
    var inputEl = document.getElementById('us');
    inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', availability, false); // error here

    function availability(name, availabilityDiv)
    {
        var name = document.getElementById('us').value;
            //code sniped
    }

}
```